# How to get Apple's @2x naming convention for retina images to work for an app with a rails backend?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, retina-display

I'm working on the rails backend of a native app.

In a native app, retina (high resolution) images are automatically loaded using the `@2x` naming convention.

For example, you can have two images called `image.png` and `image@2x.png` (the higher resolution version of the same image). If the app is running on an iPhone 3gs, `image.png` is automatically loaded. If the app is used on an iPhone 4, `image@2x.png` will be loaded automatically.

This `@2x` convention doesn't work for non-native web apps according to what I've read and seen in action.

It seems that Apple's `@2x` convention doesn't work for images supplied by a Rails backend. I know that media queries can help with this, but I'm wondering if there is some sort of work around for having an iPhone 4 automatically load `@2x` images from a web app instead of the non-highres counterpart.

Comment: You're going to need to explain this so much better if you want anyone to answer it. Especially what you mean by the @2x convention

Comment: @RyanBigg The '@2x' naming convention will be instantly familiar to any iOS developer. It's simply a way of naming an alternate, high-resolution version of an image so that it will be recognized and used by high-resolution devices.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the following:

In your rails app, create different versions of the images when uploaded.

Then in the iOS app, you could have a look at the `scale` property of `UIScreen` and determine which image to load:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f){
  //load retina image
} else {
  //load non-retina image
}
```

Comment: I've seen your answer a lot, but I'm trying to do something slightly different. Let's say in a Rails view I display <%= image_tag "image.png" %>. Even if image@2x.png exists in the same directory as image.png, the iPhone4 running the Rails app loads image.png. I know that I can determine the device pixel ratio (to determine if it's a retina device) using Javascript and store it using a cookie and then conditionally serve images based on the cookie value, but I was wondering if there's another work around that's more automatic on the client side and doesn't require the backend to use a cookie.

Comment: You say in your question that this is a native app, but yet in your comment you mention using views. Well which is it? Jakob's solution is predicated on using a native app, contacting the Rails server via an API. This will obviously not work if your iPhone app is merely opening a UIWebView and loading a view from Rails, and a server-side session var may be your only bet in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The HiSRC gem works nicely:
https://github.com/haihappen/hisrc-rails

It uses the same naming convention as Apple (@2x for retina images) and automatically serves the correct one.

I used this in conjunction with [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), creating two thumbnail versions upon upload:

```
version :retina_thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
  def full_filename (for_file = model.photo.file)
    "thumb@2x.jpg"
  end
end

version :thumb, :from_version => :retina_thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  def full_filename (for_file = model.photo.file)
    "thumb.jpg"
  end
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= responsive_image_tag user.photo_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

Another gem I tried was [Clear Eyes](https://github.com/superacidjax/clear_eyes), but I couldn't get it to work...

Answer (score 1):

Is this not the simplest solution - or do I miss something?

```
<%= image_tag("image.png", srcset: { "image@2x.png" => "2x"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a rails gem [this](https://github.com/ffaerber/retina_image_tag) should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've packaged a solutions as a gem https://github.com/jhnvz/retina_rails

Al you have to do is:

1. Add `gem 'retina_rails'` to your Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install`.
3. Add `//= require retina` to your Javascript manifest file (usually found at app/assets/javascripts/application.js).

**Carrierwave**

1. Add `include RetinaRails::CarrierWave` to the bottom of your uploader

   ```
   class ExampleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

     version :small do
       process :resize_to_fill => [30, 30]
     end

     include RetinaRails::CarrierWave

   end
   ```

**Paperclip**

1. Add `include RetinaRails::Paperclip` to the bottom of your uploader

   ```
   class ExampleUploader < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_attached_file :image,
       :styles => {
          :original => ["800x800", :jpg],
          :big => ["125x125#", :jpg]
        }

     include RetinaRails::Paperclip

   end
   ```

The gem automatically generates retina versions (appends @2x to filename) based on your defined versions in an uploader. The js checks if the users got a retina display and if so appends @2x to the image file name.

Also posted this answer in: [How do you generate retina (iPad) friendly (progressive or interlaced) jpeg images with CarrierWave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855637/how-do-you-generate-retina-ipad-friendly-progressive-or-interlaced-jpeg-imag)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this approach:

Uploading a raw file with high resolution and then just generate the 3 different sizes. Here for an Icon model I want to implement:

```
  has_attached_file :attachment,
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: Rails.configuration.aws,
  s3_protocol: :https,
  s3_host_name: 's3.amazonaws.com',
  url: ':s3_domain_url',
  path: ':class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style_:basename.:extension',
  styles: {
    '@3x_thumb': '192x192>',
    '@2x_thumb': '128x128>',
    'thumb': '64x64>'
  },
  convert_options: { 
    all: '-strip', 
    '@3x_thumb': '-quality 100 -interlace Plane', 
    '@2x_thumb': '-quality 100 -interlace Plane', 
    'thumb': '-quality 100 -interlace Plane'
    },
  :s3_headers => { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=3600' }
```

I am not sure what convert option are correct but the naming and sizing problem is solved.