# How do you generate retina (iPad) friendly (progressive or interlaced) jpeg images with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rmagick, retina-display

There are numerous reports that Mobile Safari downsamples very large JPEG images, making it difficult to put out retina-friendly resolutions for the new iPad.

The solution seems to be encoding JPEGs as progressive/interlaced files.
Hence, I'm curious how I might use the CarrierWave plugin, and RMagick by extension, to generate this type of file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [MiniMagick](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick/):

```
manipulate! do |img|
  img.strip
  img.combine_options do |c|
    c.quality "90"
    c.depth "8"
    c.interlace "plane"
  end
  img
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As of today, you will need the repository version of carriewave as `options[:write]` support is not yet released.

So in your Gemfile, use the following:

`gem 'carrierwave', :github => "jnicklas/carrierwave"`

Then, in your uploader you can define something like follow:

```
version :big do
  process :resize_to_limit => [1024, 1024]
  process :optimize
end

def optimize
  manipulate! do |img, index, options|
    options[:write] = {
      :quality => 90, # Change the quality to 90%
      :depth => 8, # Set the depth to 8 bits
      :interlace => "Magick::PlaneInterlace" # Add progressive support for JPEG
    }
    img.strip! # Remove profile data
  end
end
```

Useful reference : http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/constants.html#InterlaceType

Enjoy!

Comment: Is this then only possible with RMagick?

Comment: The solution above yes. I did not try with any other image editing library, but you can try to search for their support of such method.

Answer (score 3):

I've packaged a solutions as a gem https://github.com/jhnvz/retina_rails

Al you have to do is:

1. Add `gem 'retina_rails'` to your Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install`.
3. Add `//= require retina` to your Javascript manifest file (usually found at app/assets/javascripts/application.js).

**Carrierwave**

1. Add `include RetinaRails::CarrierWave` to the bottom of your uploader

   ```
   class ExampleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

     version :small do
       process :resize_to_fill => [30, 30]
     end

     include RetinaRails::CarrierWave

   end
   ```

**Paperclip**

1. Add `include RetinaRails::Paperclip` to the bottom of your uploader

   ```
   class ExampleUploader < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_attached_file :image,
       :styles => {
          :original => ["800x800", :jpg],
          :big => ["125x125#", :jpg]
        }

     include RetinaRails::Paperclip

   end
   ```

The gem automatically generates retina versions (appends @2x to filename) based on your defined versions in an uploader. The js checks if the users got a retina display and if so appends @2x to the image file name.

Comment: Problem here is that we now have @3x images ! And here is another discussion about this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added

Answer (score 0):

I could encode images to Progressive JPEG doing the following thing to my CarrierWave Uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :optimize #For the real image

  version :version_1 do
    # other processes
    process :optimize
  end

  version :version_2, from_version: :version_1 do
    # other processes
    process :optimize
  end

  version :version_3, from_version: :version_2 do
    # other processes
    process :optimize
  end

  def optimize
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |c|
        c.strip
        c.quality '100'
        c.depth '8'
        c.interlace 'Line'
      end
      img
    end
  end

end
```

You have to put last the process that converts the image to Progressive JPEG otherwise it won't be converted.

Then if you already have uploaded some images and you want to "re-create" them.
Imagine that your model is:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

So you have to do the following to recreate the versions:

```
Picture.order("id ASC").each do |p|
  p.image.recreate_versions! 
  puts "#{p.id}, #{p.image.url}"
end
```

I ordered the picture based on the ID because if it fails in the middle of the process I have the ID and I can continue from that ID. Another thing you can do is to rescue any exception, and save in an array the pictures that fails, something like this:

```
errored = []
Picture.order("id ASC").each do |p|
  begin
    p.image.recreate_versions! 
  rescue => e
    errored << p.id
  end
  puts "#{p.id}, #{p.image.url}"
end
```

Finally, to check that the image was converted to Progressive JPEG, having ImageMagick installed, type the following in the terminal:

```
identify -verbose PATH_TO_IMAGE | grep Interlace
```

If the image is Progressive JPEG, the output will be `Interlace: JPEG`, if not `Interlace: None`